# Installing new window a/c heater unit rated at 16 amp. Can I use 12/3 wiring or 14/3 wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Installing new window a/c heater in new family room rated at 16 amp for the heater, can I use 12/3 wiring?

Comment: What do the instructions say? If it calls for a 20a breaker (as implied by a 16a draw), then you _must_ use 12 AWG. If it calls for a 15a breaker (and only draws 16a briefly on startup), then you _can_ use 14 AWG, but it won't hurt to use 12 AWG. Also, I note you specified "/3" - is this a 240v appliance?

Comment: The absolute max for #14 is 15A per NEC 240.4(D)..... there's not like an exception "can handle more if it's a resistive load".   Why does a heater need to be in a window? [Oh, right...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto&t=0s)

Comment: Welcome to SE/Home Improvement! Please edit to provide model number or even better a link to the installation instructions. If you spend much time here you will become aware missing details cause assumptions and distractions. Here NEC 240.4(G) might let you get away with #14/2 MC cable, but practically you are asking about NM (Romex) and the air conditioner likely connects to a 20A receptacle so you need a 20A breaker and #12 wire. Please edit with a few details. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possibilities:

- 16A at startup and 12A or less when running. *Unlikely* for a bunch of reasons. But if indeed that is the case *and* the instructions do not specifically call for a 20A or larger circuit, then you can use 14 AWG wiring on a 15A circuit. But I really doubt this is the case.
- 16A continuous current draw. This is very common. Why? Because 16A is 80% of 20A, and 20A is a standard breaker size. While there are exceptions, a lot of appliances are designed to the limit of a standard circuit size. That is why a typical clothes dryer uses ~ 23A - 24A is the limit for continuous usage on a 30A circuit. That is why a standard plug-in space heater (radiant, convection, oil filled, ceramic, whatever, $30 or $200, etc.) is 1500W - that's 12A, which is the limit for continuous usage on a 15A circuit. So a 16A heater is about as standard and "natural" a size as you will find.

Once you know it is 16A continuous usage, the only real practical is 12 AWG wire on a 20A circuit.

As far as 12/3 (hot/hot/neutral + uncounted but required ground) vs. 12/2 (hot/hot + uncounted but required ground), that depends on the device requirements. You can always run neutral even if you don't need it, but if you don't need then save your money. If your device doesn't require neutral and you use 12/2 cable then you *must* mark each end of the white wire with black or red (or any color except white or green) tape or marker or similar to indicate that the white wire is a hot wire rather than neutral.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 12/3 or 14/3 (the /3 part) unless you have a wonky 4-prong plug/socket.

Condsider a dryer, which is an entirely 120V model in the version with a gas burner for heat.  On the electric variant of the same model, the 240V heating element is simply swapped in, so the rest of the dryer is still 120V.  That needs a 4-wire connection using /3 cable since it contains both 120V and 240V loads.

A/C appliances generally use 120V OR 240V, but they rarely use both at once. A big part of the reason is that affordable 4-prong sockets do not exist below 30A.  (you'd have to be up into the Twist-Lock weirdness, which has an extremely tall plug, unfit for home use. Note the vast majority of A/C plugs are right angle, so they don't get bashed by furniture. Having a Twist-Lock sticking 6" out of the wall would be quite unworkable.)

The only exception I can think would be a combo unit between a *non-reversible* 120V air conditioner and a large 240V resistive "toaster" heating element.  But that would be a super dumb product, given that the A/C unit [can be made reversible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto) cheaper than dealing with the complications of getting 4-wire 120/240V to a window A/C.

You need to provision the circuit that the instructions tell you to provision. Those instructions are approved by UL as part of the listing, and you must follow them per NEC 110.3(B).

Answer (score 0):

The TL;DR answer is that for a 16A load, you must use 12 gauge. 14 gauge is rated for a maximum of 15A, so you're over budget.

Are you sure it's 16A, though? I tend to question that because very few places have standard receptacles that go that high. In the US, for instance, your standard receptacle is 15A/120v, and most air conditioners try to stay under that limit. If it truly is 16A, it will have a 20A plug, where one of the prongs is perpendicular to the other. You'll have to have a 20A receptacle hooked to a dedicated 20A circuit to service that. If your unit is a 230v/240v unit, that further complicates things, as you'll have to have a dedicated double breaker and receptacle for that.

[image: 20 amp 240 volt plug]

Comment: There are plenty of boxes out there that need 20A @ 240V a.k.a., NEMA 6-20. [Quick search on big orange - LG](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LG-18-000-BTU-230-208-Volts-Window-Air-Conditioner-Cools-1000-Sq-Ft-with-Heater-and-Wi-Fi-Enabled-in-White-LW1823HRSM/322850194)

Comment: For the record, code does **not** require all 240V receptacles to be dedicated. For example, it’s legal to have multiple 30A / 240V receptacles in a “dryer” circuit (with the second for an EVSE, welder, etc). Usually they are dedicated (if multiple things need to run at the same time) but it is not technically a requirement.

Comment: @nobody Yeah your examples are a technical oddity I've never come to grasp with, the (UL) instructions that come with every dryer I've seen (and likely most EVSE) specify say to use an individual circuit. It's like you should have to add a label to the dryer outlet that says "do not use for clothes dryer".